# Why are more people nowadays using script to assign events handlers vs assigning the event from within the html element?

Tags: javascript, html

As a learner I like to look at lots of source code. Since I started learning JavaScript about a year ago, I notice a trend of people not using traditional event handlers as in `onclick="doSomething()"`, but are more and more using methods like `document.getElementById("someId").onclick = function(){..some code..};`

What's the reason behind this trend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assigning the handlers in Javascript puts all of the code in one place instead of scattering it throughout the HTML.
This helps separate content from script, just like CSS helps separate content from style.

It's also faster, since the browser won't need to fire up a Javascript parser for each handler attribute.

This is an example of [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript).

Comment: _<subjective>_ It's part of what separates beginner web developers from experienced professionals. _</subjective>_

Comment: @SLaks Additionally, from an architectural perspective, it makes sense to separate the behavior (JavaScript) from the presentation (HTML/CSS).  I know this is part of the definition of 'Unobtrusive JavaScript' but I think it's important to mention.

Comment: @SLaks: *"This helps separate content from script, just like CSS helps separate content from style."* Yeah, seems to me you did. ;-)

Comment: Is it really faster? I mean, the browser only *has to* use the JavaScript parser when a user clicks an element, not e.g. when rendering the document, AFAIK.

Comment: @Marcel: Even if it **is** faster in absolute terms, I can't imagine it actually makes a real-world difference. Perhaps SLaks has some data saying otherwise, but...

Comment: @Mark: I suspect not.  @T.J.: No, I don't have any data.  Unless there are a large number of inline handlers, you're probably right.

Comment: @SLaks: I disagree with your comment about it separating noobs from pros. There are occasions when using event handler attributes is entirely appropriate and arguably preferable to using script to assign the handler. An experienced professional knows the issues and uses the appropriate method.

Comment: Who is Mark? Were you actually calling me? BTW, I agree with @T.J. that in this case it doesn't matter a lot; it's almost always preferable to code sensibly and keep things as clear as possible.

Comment: @Tim Down what are the circumstances that make in-line Javascript preferable to unobtrusive Javascript?  I'm pretty much convinced that it's *never* a better idea, except perhaps on the most trivial pages - but as an experienced web developer, I don't write those :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Trivial pages is one case. Another is where it matters that behaviour is associated with an element as soon as it is rendered, for example in a large page where there are elements with scripted behaviour near the start. They can be interactive as soon as they're rendered with event handler attributes, which they cannot be if you wait until the DOM has loaded to create the event handlers.

Comment: @Tim: You can add a script block below the element without waiting for the full page to load.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes. And then you've achieved what, exactly? That's not much of a separation of concerns then: you've still got the assignment of an event handler in the HTML (inside a script), only done much more verbosely and inefficiently.

Comment: @Tim: True.  If you can break the Javascript into two distinct parts and put one entire part in the middle of the page (in an external file), it will help.

Comment: @Tim I'd (quite seriously) prefer to keep the page inactive until the script gets it all loaded than to try and make a (broken, in my opinion) design like that work (that is, "active" elements that need to work before the whole page is ready). To each his own, of course.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes you could, but that leaves you with the same basic problem. Don't get me wrong, I'm definitely in favour of avoiding event handler attributes in general; I'm just pointing out that they do have their advantages. I think they've become unfairly maligned in recent times.

Comment: @Pointy: Absolutely, I think that is generally preferable, although I don't agree that allowing scripted behaviour to work before the entire page is loaded is intrinsically broken. Why do you think it is?

Comment: Because it's inherently unpredictable. I'd rather make sure that my scripts load quickly and efficiently; that they do their page init work in a very short period of time (< 100ms at most); and that the page is as Javascript-free as possible, hopefully 100% though that's not always possible thanks to browser difficulties, templating language deficiencies, etc.

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry, must have missed that.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers haven't touched on this, so:

Your example uses the (reflected) `onclick` attribute even in the JavaScript code:

```
document.getElemenbyId("someId").onclick = function(){..some code..};
```

...which for me misses out one of the primary reasons for doing this without using attributes: Playing nicely with others. The DOM2 way of attaching handlers ([`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget), or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) on IE [IE9 has the standard `addEventListener` finally]):

```
document.getElementById("someId").addEventListener("click", function() { ... }, false);
// or
document.getElementById("someId").attachEvent("onclick", function() { ... });
```

... is *non-exclusive* — more than one handler can be attached at the same time. Whereas if you assign to `onclick`, you're kicking any previous handler off and taking over.

To me, this "playing nicely" thing is a big sell. Well, that and keeping code and markup separate, but that's been well-covered in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

HTML should be only markup, pure content.

Design should be in CSS style sheet.

Dynamic scripting should be in JavaScript code, separate file is good.

Just feels better and looks better - as far as I can tell it's not more efficient just more elegant and easier to maintain when all the script is in one place instead of being spread all across the HTML. :)

Comment: Unobstrusive JavaScript is more efficient, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people are using jQuery. `$("#someId").click(function(){})` and when you want to attach an event to many elements jQuery makes it easy and puts your function in one place.

Comment: +1.  There are plenty of good reasons for keeping the javascript separate, but those reasons aren't new.  A lot of the explanation for OP observing this change in the last year or so is due to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, the main reason is separation of concerns (in this case, keeping behaviour separate from content), which is entirely sensible. However, that isn't always the only consideration. I've previously written a [lengthy answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545826/javascript-events-where-to-place-them/3546942#3546942).